# How to restart a Python Swagger server in Docker without restarting the container

Tags: python, docker, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a Python Swagger server running as the entrypoint in a Docker container. Every few days it seems to freeze up and stop serving API requests. Restarting the container "solves" it, but I'd prefer to "hup" it in some way (while I identify the root cause of course).

The server is started in the final line of the Dockerfile thus:

```
# Run the Swagger Flask REST server
WORKDIR /app/project/python-flask-server-generated
CMD python3 -m swagger_server
```

I know how to do this for ngnix for example: `docker exec my_nginx_1 nginx -s reload`.

Is there a signal for the Python server generated by the Swagger editor?

Comment: Isn't the whole point about containers that they can be created and destroyed at will because applications are stateless? A container instance is not a VPS that would take a couple minutes to start, why are you reluctant to restart it?

Comment: I am debugging the root cause. Restarting the container just discards the problem and all evidence. Also I'm just interested in finding the documentation for what is normally easy to find: the signal interface or management app for a server (like apachectl).

Comment: I guess the answer is no. You can get a shell inside the container and `kill -HUP` the main process but for many Python webservers it will end the process and thus the container (Python webservers tend to commit seppuku and assume they will be restarted by a watchdog application). At scale some companies running Python turn the garbage collector off and just restart containers from time to time.

Comment: I was hoping for a more "apache graceful" approach to avoid dropping current connections (if I used this approach in future for regular restarts). You want to copy that comment as an answer - I don't mind accepting "no"!

Comment: In practice nobody cares to handle anything "gracefully" at the container level because the upstream load balancer is supposed to take care of it.